# What is the difference between preemptive and non-preemptive scheduling?

Tags: operating-system

I'm fresh on these term scheduling. I've become comfortable with identifying preemptive or non preemptive scheduling.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing) vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking

Answer (score 2):

Preemptive scheduling means that the scheduler (like an OS kernel) can interrupt the running tasks at any time, schedule something else and resume them later.

Non-preemptive scheduling requires the tasks to cooperate by yielding control back to the scheduler in reasonable intervals (even when they are not done with their work yet).

Comment: thanks a lot. if i have time slide , is this preemptive scheduling?

Comment: @Md.RusulAzom: Yes; if there's time slices and a task hasn't stopped using the CPU before its time slice ends, then the task is preempted so the next task can have its time slice.

Comment: According to Silberschatz et al: "Under nonpreemptive scheduling, once the CPU has been allocated to a process, the process keeps the CPU until it releases the CPU either by terminating or by switching to the waiting state". According to this definition, they do not mention yielding control back to the scheduler in reasonable intervals even when they are not done with their work yet. Is there possibly varying industry definitions to the term?

Comment: @DeanP That says the same thing, no? Under non-preemptive scheduling the process keeps the CPU until it "yields" (by switching to the waiting state). If it does not do that, the scheduler/OS cannot give the CPU to another process.